# What is the reference for taming a ferocious bathhouse Naga into a tiny snake in a bowl?

Tags: reference-request, sutras

I remember Ajahn Punnadhammo telling a story about maybe the Buddha or Moggallana taming a ferocious bathhouse Naga and emerging from the bathhouse displaying that it was now a small snake in a bowl. What is the canonical or otherwise reference for this story?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vinaya, Mahavagga, [Uruvelapāṭihāriyakathā](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/vin/mv/mv01/mv.01.12.khem_en.html) good householder. Can "anonymous" serve anonymous else?
It would be much better to approach Ajahn gratefully personal.

Comment: Ata,bot thank ya